# how do i force a user to go back twice on a mobile web page using php or javascript without the user clicking any link or button

Tags: php, javascript, redirect, back-button

how do I force a user to go back twice on a mobile web page using PHP or jAVASCRIPT without the user clicking any link or button.
something like using history.back() without a user having to click on anything

Comment: Where is the code or what you have tried..?

Comment: what I have tried: history.back() , window.history.go(-2) and that did not work because I do not want a user to click on a button inorder to go back twice. if($condition): window.history.go(-2); endif;

Answer (score 2):

In javascript

```
function goBackTwice()
{
window.history.go(-2)
}
```

You may want to look into https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/ for a more robust client side solution.

Comment: thanks thou window.history.go(-2) works on a button click..I need one that will not require a user to click on anything

Comment: not true - you didn't specify the conditions under which you want the user to be redirected, so I gave you a function that could be used with any event e.g. onload="goBackTwice()" would send the user back as soon as the element is rendered.